# Strange warning C4691 when using .NET 3.5 library from .NET 4 project

Tags: c#, c++-cli

If I have a .NET 3.5, C# project with the following class:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Method1(Func<int> func)
        {

        }

        public static void Method2()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And I attempt to use it from a .NET 4.0, C++/CLI project like so:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace ClassLibrary1;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Class1::Method2();
    return 0;
}
```

The C++/CLI project compiles with the following warning:

> warning C4691: 'System::Func' : type referenced was expected in
>   unreferenced assembly 'System.Core', type defined in current
>   translation unit used instead 2>          This diagnostic occurred
>   while importing type 'ClassLibrary1::Class1 ' from assembly
>   'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

Note that a similar .NET 4.0 C# project using this library will compile without warning, so this is specific to C++/CLI. Referencing System.Core from the project doesn't remove the warning. The warning seems useful in general so I'm reluctant to disable it, is there anything else I can do about it?

This was observed in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.

Comment: I think it is trying to say that it was expecting to find System.Func in the 3.5 version of System.Core. But since you don't have that referenced it used the 4.0 definition instead. You might try some other system types in the library and see if you get the same warning.

Comment: Whether or not a compiler should emit a diagnostic when it looks for possible method overloads, and can't nail it down because it just has no idea what the method looks like, is not part of the language specification.  This was changed in a recent version of the C# compiler as well btw, many questions about it.  Trivial to solve of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a framework version mismatch as your C# project is built in .net 3.5 and you are referencing it in a c++ project that's using .net 4.0

My suggestion would be to assign the same framework version for both the projects, either 3.5 or 4.0

Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy1c794f.aspx) that explains this warning in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this is the covariance changes for .Net 4.0. In this case, the .Net 3.5 definition is:

```
public delegate TResult Func<TResult>()
```

While the .Net 4.0 definition is:

```
public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>()
```

Using other .Net library items (I tried `List<T>`) without any changes does not produce this error.

I would only be concerned about this warning if I was attempting to use the delegate in a covariant manner. With a `Func<int>` that is unlikely.